# BaseX XSLT fails after returning first result

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, basex

I have a large XML file stored in BaseX that I need to split up into smaller, modular documents. I have created an XSL file to do so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="schema"/>
    <xsl:param name="model"/>
    <xsl:param name="sysDiff"/>
    <xsl:param name="sys"/>
    <xsl:param name="subsys"/>
    <xsl:param name="subsubsys"/>
    <xsl:param name="assy"/>
    <xsl:param name="disassy"/>
    <xsl:param name="disassyv"/>
    <xsl:param name="info"/>
    <xsl:param name="infov"/>
    <xsl:param name="itemloc"/>
    <xsl:param name="tname"/>
    <xsl:param name="iname"/>
    <xsl:param name="outputDir"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="{concat($outputDir, '/DMC-',$model,'-',$sysDiff,'-',$sys,'-',$subsys,$subsubsys,'-',$assy,'-',$disassy,$disassyv,'-',$info,$infov,'-',$itemloc,'.xml')}" method="xml">
            <dmodule>
                <identAndStatusSection>
                    <dmAddress>
                        <dmIdent>
                            <dmCode modelIdentCode="{$model}" systemDiffCode="{$sysDiff}">
                                <xsl:attribute name="systemCode" select="$sys"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="subSystemCode" select="$subsys"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="subSubSystemCode" select="$subsubsys"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="assyCode" select="$assy"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="disassyCode" select="$disassy"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="disassyCodeVariant" select="$disassyv"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="infoCode" select="$info"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="infoCodeVariant" select="$infov"/>
                                <xsl:attribute name="itemLocationCode" select="$itemloc"/>
                            </dmCode>
                            <language languageIsoCode="en" countryIsoCode="US"/>
                            <issueInfo issueNumber="000" inWork="01"/>
                        </dmIdent>
                    </dmAddress>
                </identAndStatusSection>
            </dmodule>
        </xsl:result-document>    
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My issue is that when using the xslt:transform() function in BaseX it only returns (creates) the first document. This is the XQuery I have for this:

```
 let $style := doc('file:///C:/base.xsl')

   for $d in doc('file:///C:/Users/tfurst/Documents/Book1-test.xml')//title
      for $newD in //*[title]
      where $newD/title/@id eq $d/@id
        let $schema := $d/schemaName
        let $model := $d/modelic
        let $sdc := $d/sdc
        let $sys := $d/systemCode
        let $subsys := $d/subsys
        let $subsubsys := $d/subsubsys
        let $assy := $d/assy
        let $disassy := $d/disassy
        let $disassyv := $d/disassyv
        let $info := $d/infoCode
        let $infov := $d/infov
        let $itemloc := $d/itemloc
        let $tname := $d/tname
        let $iname := $d/iname
        return xslt:transform($newD,$style, map {"outputDir":"file:///G:/LMA-Conv/Flight/test-conv-out", "model":$model, "sysDiff":$sdc, "sys":$sys, "subsys":$subsys, "subsubsys":$subsubsys, "assy":$assy, "disassy":$disassy, "disassyv":$disassyv, "info":$info, "infov":$infov, "itemloc":$itemloc, "tname":$tname, "iname":$iname})
```

The document named Book1-test.xml is essentially a map of existing IDs of elements to new output file names. After it creates the first XML output file BaseX returns ERROR [FODC0002] "" (Line 1): Premature end of file. When I looked up the error code in the BaseX documentation this error is defined as **"The specified document resource cannot be retrieved. "**. Is there some limitation to the use of the xslt:transform function in a loop? I am not understanding why it was able to retrieved the first time, but not after that. I have tried to move the XSL to different file locations, no luck. Am I missing something ridiculously obvious here?

Comment: It might be a bug, I think the desired approach is to ask for confirmation on the BaseX mailing list, then they open an issue on https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex. For the simple stylesheet you have (where you just populate some result elements with parameters passed in from XQuery) you should of course be able to do that stuff in XQuery (`<dmCode modelIdentCode="{$model}" systemDiffCode="{$sysDiff}" systemCode="{$sys}">`) without XSLT, using `fn:put` or https://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module to write the files.

Comment: This is just the beginning of the XSLT, the node being pulled from the BaseX DB ($newD) is then going to being transformed to become the content of the new file. I was using this simple beginning to get the process down and started. I may take the file module approach and perform the XSLT outside of the DB environment.

Comment: BaseX are rather fast in fixing bugs so if you tell them about the problem you might have a new snapshot with a fix within a few days or faster.

Comment: Note that there is one oddity, your stylesheet matches on `/` which would be a document node but you pass in an element node `$newD` so your stylesheet might not do what you expect.

Comment: The single output it created was what I had anticipated for this minimal start. My thought was that when retrieving each node in BaseX, that each result was being treated as standalone document, which I am converting a new, standalone document. I successfully queried and saved all 325 results to separate documents, I may just run the XSL against those rather than through BaseX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Gerrit Imsieke on the BaseX mailing list has the right explanation, BaseX doesn't fail to process the second input to XSLT, it fails to convert the empty result of your first call to `xslt:transform` to any of its XQuery representations. So using `xslt:transform-text` instead should fix your problem. Or having the XSLT output a primary result with a root element.

Comment: using the xslt:transform-text() function did the trick. Thank you for your help Martin.